# useEffect call the function after the state is updated

Tags: reactjs

I have the useEffect function

```
useEffect(() => {
  let branchName = getBranchName();
  setBranchName(branchName);
  refreshBranchStatus()
}, []);
```

I want to call the `refreshBranchStatus()`function once, after setting the state of `branchName`

I tried write `await` before `setBranchName(branchName);`
but it didn't work.
I tried write a second function

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
      await refreshBranchStatus();
    }
  }, [branchName]);
```

but it is called even when branchName has not changed(after page load, not after `setBranchName(branchName);`)

How can I get the correct behavior?
thanks in advance

Comment: can i see your usestate for setBranchName?

Comment: `const [branchName, setBranchName] = useState('');`

Answer (score 4):

A key question to first ask yourself is:

> Should `refreshBranchStatus` be re-invoked if `branchName` changes?

If it *depends* on the value of `branchName` then in the majority of cases, yes, it probably should be re-invoked.  But a comment thread on this answer seems to be implying that this is an obscure case where it depends on the value but *shouldn't* be re-invoked if that value changes.

Based on the answer to the above, there are two approaches:

---

**Option 1: Re-invoke when state changes**

Create a second effect.  The first is triggered only once when the component is first loaded:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let newBranchName = getBranchName();
  setBranchName(newBranchName);
}, []);
```

The other is triggered when the `branchName` state value changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  refreshBranchStatus();
}, [branchName]);
```

**Note:** This should also run on the initial load because the `branchName` state value "changed" (or "was set to") its initial state.  So I'd expect this effect to be executed twice.  Once on the initial state of `branchName` and once on the updated state of `branchName`.  (And again on any subsequent updates of that state.)

---

**Option 2: Remove the dependency on state**

If you truly only want to invoke `refreshBranchStatus` once, and only once, when the component first loads **and** it needs the value of `branchName` to execute then you should pass that value to the function.  Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let newBranchName = getBranchName();
  setBranchName(newBranchName);
  refreshBranchStatus(newBranchName);
}, []);
```

In this scenario `refreshBranchStatus` isn't internally checking the `branchName` state but is more of a "pure" function which requires that it be provided with the value it needs.  Since you have that value when you invoke the function, just pass it to the function.

Comment: I tried write second useEffect, but the second effect is fired right after the page is loaded, and not after the state branchName changed by setBranchName function.
And I need call refreshBranchStatus(); only once

Comment: @guest381: I'd expect it to be executed both times.  Once for the initial state of `branchName` and then again for the updated state of `branchName`.  Is that not the case?  If it's failing in some way because the initial state of `branchName` is invalid for that operation then that's a separate concern.  Can you clarify what specifically is failing?

Comment: it doesn't work because there is condition `if (isFirstRender.current) ` isFirstRender default true. Condition is necessary in order not to call refreshBranchStatus every time the branch is changed, because the UI has a button for this

Comment: @guest381: `isFirstRender` implies a bit of a hack to me.  It sounds like you're trying to fight React's re-rendering instead of using it as intended.  When *should* `refreshBranchStatus` execute?  If it depends on the value of `branchName` then logically it should execute any time `branchName` changes, shouldn't it?  If `branchName` can be changed, why don't you want `refreshBranchStatus` to re-execute when `branchName` changes?

Comment: because refreshBranchStatus calls http request to the backend server which takes a long time, and second because there is a button "Refresh" in the UI which call refreshBranchStatus too

Comment: @guest381: So then `refreshBranchStatus` *shouldn't* be invoked when `branchName` changes?  Even though it depends on `branchName`?

Comment: @guest381: I've updated the answer with another option.  If `refreshBranchStatus` shouldn't depend on the state of `branchName` then don't have it internally read that state value.  Instead, pass the value to it when it's invoked.  Then you can keep it in the same `useEffect` for when the component first loads.

Comment: `refreshBranchStatus` should be called once, after loading the page and after getting the value from `getBranchName` and setting the state `branchName`

Comment: Thanks for you help @David

Answer (score 0):

Every `usEffect` will be called on the initial render of the component, so if you're waiting for a value to be set, you need to check for it in the effect body.

I think what you're asking for could be achieved like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let branchName = getBranchName();
  setBranchName(branchName);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (branchName) refreshBranchStatus();
}, [branchName]);
```