# Why does the second function in my useEffect() hook think a state value is undefined after the first function set the state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a react component displaying details about a trip.
The component queries the db for this data in 2 consecutive queries.
The first query includes a destination_id and a list of participant ids.
The second query uses that destination_id to get details on the destination.
I am storing the details in React state variables.
The second query thinks tripDetails.destination_id is undefined. I think this means the first function's call to setTripDetails() has not completed before the second query starts.

Here was my original code...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTrip = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/trips/' + trip_id, { trip_id: trip_id });
        setTripDetails(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        Alert.alert('This trip could not be found. id=' + trip_id);
        console.log('error fetching trip details: ' + JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      }
    };
    const getDestination = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/destinations/' + tripDetails.destination_id);
        setDestination(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error fetching destination details: ' + JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      }
    };

    const getAllTripDetails = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      await getTrip();
      await getDestination();
      setIsLoading(false);
    };
    getAllTripDetails();
  }, []);
```

I tried refactoring according to option 1 in David's answer on [this similar stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71146430/useeffect-call-the-function-after-the-state-is-updated) as follows...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTrip = async () => {
      console.log('getting trip');
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await api.get('/trips/' + trip_id, { trip_id: trip_id });
        setTripDetails(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error fetching trip details: ' + JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      }
    };
    getTrip();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDestination = async () => {
      console.log('getting destination');
      try {
        const response = await api.get('/destinations/' + tripDetails.destination_id);
        setDestination(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error fetching destination details: ' + JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      }
    };

    if (tripDetails) {
      getDestination();
    }
  }, [tripDetails]);
```

This works, but I'm not sure I am using the useEffect hooks 100% correctly such that this won't cause other problems down the line.

Comment: Your first `useEffect` needs also `[trip_id]` as second parameter. Currently it will execute on every rerender.

Comment: Reference the first API result directly instead of referencing the stateful variable, which has not updated due to the stale closure. I think a single effect hook would make a bit more sense. Your first code was almost there.

Comment: In the first useEffect, pass an empty array as dependency if you want to run it only once:
```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getTrip = async () => {
      console.log('getting trip');
      try {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const response = await api.get('/trips/' + trip_id, { trip_id: trip_id });
        setTripDetails(response.data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error fetching trip details: ' + JSON.stringify(err.response.data));
      }
    };
    getTrip();
  }, []);
```